# error: 'str' object has no attribute 'update' when adding key to dict

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, dictionary

quite a newbie question, so please bear with me....

i'm using python 2.7.8 with Django 1.7.1.

i'm trying to add a key to a dict within a for loop.

```
courseProgress =  dict()
for child in children:
    courseProgress[child.id] = str(child.child_firstname)
for individualCourse in allCourses:
    #get the total number of items within a course
    totalContentsCount = len(courseContents[individualCourse.course_id])
    #get the total number of completed steps for this course from the rewardHistory that we obtained earlier
    thisCourseProgress = len(allCourses.filter(course = individualCourse.course_id))
    #divide to get a percentage
    thisProgress = float(thisCourseProgress) / float(totalContentsCount)
    currentCourseID = int(individualCourse.course_id)
    thisCourse = {
        'progress' : thisProgress,
        'courseInfo' : courseContents[currentCourseID]
        }
    courseProgress[individualCourse.child.id].update({currentCourseID : thisCourse})
```

the last line generates the error: **error: 'str' object has no attribute 'update'**

obviously(?) it's seeing courseProgress[individualCourse.child.id] as a string and not as a key within a dictionary to which i'm trying to add a child key. I think this is because i'm getting the value returned (which is a string). Within an interactive prompt i get the following:

```
>>>courseProgress[individualCourse.child.id]
'Sophie'
```

I'm not sure why this is...

**The result i'm after** is to add a child key to `courseProgress[individualCourse.child.id]` (e.g. `courseProgress[1]` ), and that child key would be in the eventual format of `{1 : thisCourse}`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: your line would only work if the result of `courseProgress[individualCourse.child.id]` were a dictionary itself

Comment: `courseProgress[child.id] = str(child.child_firstname)` sets your values to *strings*. Strings indeed don't have an `update` method. What did want to happen here?

Comment: If you expected the values to be dictionaries instead, you'd have to actually create a dictionary there, instead of strings.

Comment: many thanks guys. looks like the root cause of this is to simply change the value from a str() to a dict(). i'll give that a shot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this ...

```
for child in children:
    courseProgress[child.id] = {
                   name: str(child.child_firstname),
                   courses: {}
                 }
```

and then

```
courseProgress[individualCourse.child.id]['courses'].update({currentCourseID : thisCourse})
```

Comment: what worked for me was the following:     
for child in children:
        courseProgress[child.id] = dict()

Comment: i'll mark your answer as correct since, whilst not exactly the same as my end code it still works... the end effect of declaring an empty dictionary is what fixed it.... thanks to Martijn Pieters as well!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to update() a string not a dict.
I think you should have a different data structure, now you have a dict where the keys are integer and the values are string.
You need a dict of dict.

`{key1: {}, key2: {}}`

You could simple change the str() for {}.

Another approach to dont mix "the name" and the "couses" is to do something like

```
for child in children:
    courseProgress[child.id] = {
        'name': child.child_firstname,  #child_name
        'courses': {}  #map of courses course_id: course
    }
```

then you could do:

```
courses = courseProgress[individualCourse.child.id]['courses']
courses.update({currentCourseID:thisCourse})
```

if you want the info of a given child.id and course you could do
couseProgress[childId]['courses'][someCourseId]

Instead of having that kind of complex datastructure sometimes its better to createa class :).